# How to select a row with flexible elements?

Tags: select, row, selenium-ide

I have a table and I need to select a row, but my elements have the ID variable. To select the row I have to click in a button at the left side of the specification of the products`s name. How can I do that?

The ID of my product is the following: xpath=(//div[@id='1478590880658-grid-container']/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div)[2] and the position: //div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div
The ID of the button at the left side of the name of the product is: //div[@id='1478590880658-grid-container']/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div and the position: //div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use *Click* or *clickAt* commands in Selenium to perform the clicking action and pass our location as argument.

Try this in the source mode:

```
<td>click</td>
<td> //div[@id='1478590880658-grid-container']/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div</td>
<td></td>
```

But for Click command to work, the location should be specified properly.

If you are not already using [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) with Firebug, I would recommend you to install them. They work with Mozilla and are a great help for beginners learning Xpath.